Power of Test in a Coin Toss Experiment
I am trying to understand the concept of "Power of Test" using the example of a coin experiment.
I have a coin that I want to prove is biased towards heads. I toss the coin 10 times, and get 9 heads and 1 tails. The probability of this happening to a fair coin is $0.0107$. On Excel, we can calculate this as:
= BINOM.DIST(9, 10, 0.5, 0) + BINOM.DIST(10, 10, 0.5, 0). Or I can calculate this manually as $\binom{10}{9}\cdot0.5^9\cdot0.5^1 + \binom{10}{10}\cdot0.5^{10}\cdot0.5^0 = 0.0107$
This probability is so low, that I can say I have enough evidence to claim that the coin is not fair.
$H_0$ = Coin is Fair; $H_A$ = Coin is biased towards heads
Assuming $H_0$, the probability of at least 9 heads in 10 tosses - the $p-value$ - is so low that I reject $H_0$.
Is $0.0107$ the probability of incorrectly rejecting $H_0$? And $1-0.0107$ the probability of correctly not rejecting the null hypothesis (confidence)? How can I interpret this "confidence"?
And then, how do I calculate power of the test, and interpret it in this situation?
Thanks for your help!

In your example, $H_A$ is a composite (rather than simple) hypothesis. In this case, we have to ask what exactly does it mean for $H_A$ to be true? The power here will be a function of the true value of $p > 0.5$.
For example, suppose that the true proportion of heads is $p=0.7$ and we use a testing procedure which rejects $H_0$ if there are at least $9$ out of $10$ heads. The size of this test is $0.0107$, as you computed in the original question. The power of this test is a function of $p$ and can be computed as
$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_i \geq 9 \bigg| p=0.7\right) = \binom{9}{10} 0.7^9(1-0.7)^{10-1} + \binom{10}{10} 0.7^{10}(1-0.7)^{10-10} \approx 0.149.$$
So the power is just $0.149$, but this value will change for different values of $p > 0.5$.



True $p$
Power




0.51
0.0126


0.6
0.0464


0.7
0.149


0.9
0.736




For fixed $p$, you can increase the power by using a test based on a larger sample size. For example, suppose that now we will flip the coin $n=40$ times, and we will reject $H_0$ whenever there are at least $26$ heads. In R, the size of this test is given by
1 - pbinom(25, 40, 0.5)

which gives $0.0403$. The power (for given $p>0.5$) is found via
1 - pbinom(25, 40, p_A)




True $p$
Power




0.51
0.0526


0.6
0.317


0.7
0.807


0.9
0.999




Thanks for the explaination!
Using the null hypothesis rejection criteria of at least 9 heads of 10 toss, I will not be able to detect a small biasness towards heads (true p = 0.6, probability of correctly rejecting null hypothesis is low or, power = 0.0464), but if I do get at least 9 out of 10 heads, I can be fairly certain that the coin is biased (p-value = 0.0107). Instead, if I was trying to detect a large biasness (true p = 0.9), this criteria is much better (power = 0.736).

If I change the criteria to at least 6 heads of 10 toss, I will be able to detect the true p = 0.6 with power = 0.63, but I can't reject null hypothesis as p-value = 0.38.
I can extend this logic and design a test that can do both: a rejection criteria of at least 536 heads of 1000 toss allows me to detect true p = 0.6 with a power of 0.99, while still giving strong evidence of biasness (p-value = 0.0105).

@DragonClaw You have to be careful with terminology. What you are calling p-value is actually called the "size" of the test (also called $\alpha$, the significance level, or the type I error rate). The P-value is calculated from the data, and we reject if $p < \alpha$.

@DragonClaw. But yes -- you are generally thinking about this in a useful way. There is always a tradeoff between the size and power of a test (or equivalently, a tradeoff between the Type I and Type II errors). The best you can do to ensure satisfactory values for both, is to increase the sample size.
